Text overflow with icons in rich text in Flutter
I have the following code:
    final users = [
      (name: 'Muhammad', showIcon: true),
      (name: 'Christopher', showIcon: false),
      (name: 'Michael', showIcon: true),
      (name: 'Robert', showIcon: false),
      // (name: 'John', showIcon: true),
      // (name: 'William', showIcon: true),
      // (name: 'Richard', showIcon: false),
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
            children: List.generate(
              users.length,
              (index) {
                final user = users[index];
                return TextSpan(
                  text: user.name,
                  children: [
                    if (user.showIcon)
                      const WidgetSpan(
                        child: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
                        alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
                      ),
                    if (index < users.length - 1) const TextSpan(text: ', '),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      ),
    );

This is the result:

This is exactly what I want, to show an icon after some of the names.
Now if I uncomment the remaining items of the users list, the result will be:

This almost looks as I expect, to show ... at the end of the line when it is longer, but what I want in this specific case is, if an icon should be shown after the name, then the icon should remain at the end of the line and just the name should be ellipsized, like: Willi....
Note: The behavior should be the same for texts with multiple lines, for example, maxLines: 2 or maxLines: 3.
